# Setting variables on CASE results in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm sure the answer is simple, but I have been searching for a while and can't seem to get this working ...
I am tring to set a variable based on a Case statement result.

So I am checking length of two columns

```
dbo.MY_TABLES.MY_RULESET, 
dbo.MY_TABLES.MY_SPECIFICATION
```

My case statements check If length/75 is over 1 then we return 1. If under 1, then we return the value (under 1)
I then want to add these two results together and is where im getting problems when i need the addtion dependant on the case results.

Here is sample

```
Declare @SpecValue FLOAT
Declare @RuleValue FLOAT

SELECT 
CAST(LEN(MY_SPECIFICATION) AS FLOAT)/75 as Score1,
CAST(LEN (MY_RULESET) AS FLOAT)/75 AS Score2,

CASE
WHEN (CAST(LEN(MY_SPECIFICATION) AS FLOAT)/75) >1 Then '1'
ELSE (Round(CAST(LEN(MY_SPECIFICATION) AS FLOAT)/75,2))
END as Spec1_RuleLength,


CASE 
When (CAST(LEN (MY_RULESET) AS FLOAT)/75) >1 Then '1'
ELSE (Round(CAST(LEN (MY_RULESET) AS FLOAT)/75,2))
END as Eval2_RuleLength,

dbo.MY_TABLES.MY_RULESET, 
dbo.MY_TABLES.MY_SPECIFICATION


FROM MY_TABLES
```

Comment: You should unqoute the '1' after `Then` if you plan to use it as a number. Also, what is the error message you see?

Comment: Good point about the '1' - Thanks.
Well I was hoping this would work... 
Set @SpecValue = Case When......
I get this error
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Set'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All columns in a `SELECT` clause are computed as if they're evaluated in parallel. This means that one column cannot depend on the value of another column computed in the same `SELECT`.

You might try moving the current query into a subselect:

```
SELECT Score1 + Score2 /* etc */
FROM (
    SELECT 
    CAST(LEN(MY_SPECIFICATION) AS FLOAT)/75 as Score1,
    CAST(LEN (MY_RULESET) AS FLOAT)/75 AS Score2,

    CASE
    WHEN (CAST(LEN(MY_SPECIFICATION) AS FLOAT)/75) >1 Then '1'
    ELSE (Round(CAST(LEN(MY_SPECIFICATION) AS FLOAT)/75,2))
    END as Spec1_RuleLength,


    CASE 
    When (CAST(LEN (MY_RULESET) AS FLOAT)/75) >1 Then '1'
    ELSE (Round(CAST(LEN (MY_RULESET) AS FLOAT)/75,2))
    END as Eval2_RuleLength,

    dbo.MY_TABLES.MY_RULESET, 
    dbo.MY_TABLES.MY_SPECIFICATION


    FROM MY_TABLES
) t
```

Comment: The Subquery method is exactly what I needed - Thanks Damien.  

What I actually have done is this:

((Select CASE WHEN (CAST(LEN(EY_STANDARD_SPECIFICATION) AS FLOAT)/@SpecComplete) >1 Then 1
ELSE (Round(CAST(LEN(EY_STANDARD_SPECIFICATION) AS FLOAT)/@SpecComplete,2))
END) + (Select CASE WHEN (CAST(LEN(MY_Ruleset) AS FLOAT)/75) >1 When 1 ELSE (Round(CAST(LEN(MY_SPECIFICATION) AS FLOAT)/75,2))
END)) as Total